# Calling unnamed controller and method in a router

Tags: php, model-view-controller, routes, router

Looking at altorouter Q&A, I found this example [here](https://github.com/dannyvankooten/AltoRouter/issues/57) on how to call a named controller and method when using altorouter.

```
$router->map('GET','/content/[:parent]/?[:child]?', 'content_controller#display_item', 'content');
```

The syntax

```
$router(method, route, target, name(optional));
```

I get how to map the method, route but do not understand how to get the target to map/call an unnamed controller or method?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it seems to work but I'll yet need confirmation if this is how we are supposed to it

```
$router->map('GET', '/[a:controller]/[a:action]?', function ($controller, $action = null) {
    if ($action=='') {$action = 'index';}
    if (method_exists($controller, $action)) {
        $controller::$action();
    } else {
        echo 'missing';
    }
});
```

Here the router is `/[a:controller]/[a:action]?` and the target is a function

```
function ($controller, $action = null) {
    if ($action=='') {$action = 'index';}
    if (method_exists($controller, $action)) {
        $controller::$action();
    } else {
        echo 'missing';
      }
    });
```

which get the unnamed controller and checks for the method/action. If the method/action is null index is assigned to the variable $action and then mapped.

Please confirm if it is the right war of calling an undefined controller and mehtod